# How to check windows service is installed or not from azure devops command line task?

Tags: command-line, azure-devops, windows-services

Im using **command line task** in azure devops to install windows service.

First i need to check if service is already installed or not before going to uninstall it.

i use 
**SC QUERY**  to check service exists or not

my full script as follows

```
@echo off
SC \\myserver QUERY servicename > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1060 GOTO MISSING
ECHO SERVICE FOUND UNINSTALLING!
SC \\myserver STOP servicename
SC \\myserver DELETE servicename
GOTO END

:MISSING
ECHO COULD NOT FIND SERVICE!
GOTO END

:END
```

this works fine in local environment , but when task runs it fails with following error.

***##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1060'.***

is anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is because the error still exists as DevOps exists the script. If you want to catch the specific error code you could exit with zero.

```
@echo off
SC \\myserver QUERY servicename > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1060 GOTO MISSING
ECHO SERVICE FOUND UNINSTALLING!
SC \\myserver STOP servicename
SC \\myserver DELETE servicename
GOTO END

:MISSING
ECHO COULD NOT FIND SERVICE!
EXIT 0

:END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Batch Script task to run the script:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/batch-script?view=azure-devops